# Scrolling Content With Fixed Navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck here. I can't quite figure out the correct syntax to get the layout of my site exactly right.

I am attempting to have a side navigation of a fixed width that is 100% height, then a top nav that is fixed height that is 100% width, finally I want my content to take up the remaining space and have independent scrolling.

The issue I am having is that the content scroll bar is being overlapped by the topNav bar.

I currently have my CSS set up as follows:

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.sideNav
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 3;
}

.topNav
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: gold;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: right;
}
.content
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background-color: blue;
overflow-y: scroll;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
padding-left: 100px;
border: 2px red inset;
margin-top: 65px;
}
```

Here is the Fiddle as I know this sounds confusing: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cRL3/)

Let me know if there is anything else I can provide. I've exhausted all of my ideas.

Comment: I see what you describe on jsFiddle, just change the size of the result window

Comment: You should consider using a grid system, or at least inspire yourself from it, here is a code sample https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L774-L1395

Comment: @JonathandeM. I'm not sure what you mean by change the size of the result window. The problem I am having is the overlap of the top nav covering the scroll bar in the content. A grid system would also not fix this problem what so ever.

Comment: change margin-top:65px by top:65px then

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it working.  Just needed to remove the float on the sidebar (it's being positioned absolutely, so there's no need for it), and then offset its position from the top by the height of the top nav.  Like so...

```
.sideNav
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    /*float: right; - not needed */
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px; /* offset by the height of the top nav bar */
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 3;
}
.content
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background-color: blue;
overflow-y: scroll;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
position: absolute;
/* bottom: 0; - position from top instead for consistency */
top: 65px;
right: 0;
padding-left: 100px;
border: 2px red inset;
/* margin-top: 65px; - no longer needed */
}
```

here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7cRL3/

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. The issue I am having is in the content section where the scroll bar is overlapped by the topNav

Comment: I've added to my answer

Comment: Right, but now the bottom of the scroll bar is cut off due to the div being 65px from the top. See my issue? The only way I can think of is to use the `calc` function in the css height.